# MKMap not using defined Lat and Long

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

I have a TabBar application. The first view is a loading screen that calls all of my web-services and db function. It then pushes to my first tab a MKmap.

[image: Layout]

The problem Im having is that that my map is being displayed as default with no values even then my set lat and long function is being run.

If I change the entry point to the tabBarViewController it works fine. 
after many hours of googling I could not work out ho to fix this. 
What could be causing this to happen?

Here is my Map [code](http://pastebin.com/6UgeU1Fr).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm pretty sure the operations of all your tab bar controller needs to be on the main thread, but not sure whether you have included them or not. it seems like these operations are on a thread (but not main thread).

That’s exactly what Grand Central Dispatch gives you on Mac OS X, and now iOS — access to concurrency without nearly as much pain.

The problem is not with your map, you are on the wrong queue.

Answer (score 1):

On first impression I noticed 2 things.

1: `showMapView.mapType= MKMapTypeStandard;` I'm not sure if this should even compile?  It should be `self.showMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard`

2: you ran `#import "MapViewController.h"` twice

If you can paste `MapViewController.h` that might help with debugging also

Comment: Thanks I have made those changes.